# Can't show the nodes in the user interface OpenDaylight

Tags: ubuntu, mininet, openflow, opendaylight

I have made this topology using Miniedit :

[image]

Then I have started opendaylight lithium :

[image]

The pingall test is successful but I can't see the topology in opendaylight web user interface :

[image]

These are the settings of the controller I'm using:

[image]

These are the general settings of Miniedit:

[image]

For opendaylight, I have installed odl-dlux-all, odl-openvswitch-switch, odl-restconf, and odl-openvswitch-switch-ui.

Why can't I see the topology in DLUX? Is there any other way to show it?
I use Ubuntu 15.04.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screen shots indicate Opendaylight controller and mininet are running on the same machine. It appears that controller has not even discovered the switch node. Please make sure that Opendaylight and Mininet OVS are connected. Please try following commands:
1. netstat -anp|grep 6633 (This will dump the list of connections on port 6633)
2. ovs-vsctl show (This will give you the connection status)

If Mininet and Controller are connected, please check following:
1. Capture the OpenFlow packets between controller and switch using command - tcpdump -i any -eXtn port 6633
2. Try to fetch the topology information using REST API
3. Check controller logs for any errors.